# Problem on changing EPSG:3376 to EPSG:4326 using Proj4js

Tags: proj4js

I been using the proj4js to transform the projection1 ([EPSG::3376](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::3376)) to projection2 ([EPSG::4326](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326)) with the data location of `[66333, 170175]` the outcome is supposed to be `[110.281820983;1.5390299426]` where I test it on the https://mygeodata.cloud/cs2cs/ and test it on https://epsg.io but when it transforms it turns to `[115.59856224058234, 5.5388802885425905]`.

Can I know what are the problem with it?

Here is my code

```
    var firstProjection     = '+proj=omerc +lat_0=4 +lonc=115 +alpha=53.31580995 +k=0.99984 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +no_uoff +gamma=53.13010236111111 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs';
    var secondProjection    = '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs';
    var point               = proj4(firstProjection,secondProjection,[66333,170175]);
```

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: EPSG:4326 is lat long, so 110.28...,1.5... is not correct

Comment: i had add in my code. By the way, why the lat long is not correct? I try it show the correct position on the map.

Comment: I confusing with the input coordinate actually any clarification on the input coordinate of proj4js ? Does the x and y stand for the easting and northing or latitude or longtitude?

Comment: `... By the way, why the lat long is not correct?` because EPSG::4326 coordinates are specified in latitude then longitude order, latitude has range +/-90 degrees, and your first value is `110.28` so that can't be a correct latitude value

Comment: X is the first axis and Y is the second axis as defined by the specific CRS, so X may be easting, or northing, or westing, or southing, or latitude or longitude

Answer (score 1):

1)
E 66333 N 170175 in EPSG:3376 is indeed E 110.281820983 N 1.5390299426 in EPSG:4326.
If you had obtained any other result, it could be that:-

(a) The converter is buggy,
(b) You typed wrongly,
(c) Both the above.

2)
Do take note that what you had done is to express a coordinate in the GDM2000 reference frame as long/lat in WGS84 ellipsoid. This does not transform your coordinate in the GDM2000 reference frame into the WGS84 Gxxxx reference frame.